# How to fit a model to data with asymetric errors?

Tags: chi-squared-test, model, fitting, curve-fitting

I need to fit a model to some data. I fit models like this all the time. Usually, the data has symmetric errors (i.e. x ± error). When its like this, I can minimize Chi^2 no problem (Chi^2 = [(data-model)/(error)]^2) and get a best-fit. But now I a dealing with errors that are asymmetric (i.e. x + high error -low error) and I am not sure how to do this, even in principle. Could the denominator in Chi^2 be some kind of average between the high and low error? I can't find anything online that directly addresses my question.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. The model is very simple: I have a single parameter "N" that I tune to fit the model to the data. N is a constant multiplier to a curve I get from simulations.

Comment: Please be more specific about what model you are trying to fit.  How do you know the errors are asymmetric (they are unobservable quantities)? What is the nature of your data? You have an outcome, presumably, and a predictor? You write  "I can minimize Chi^2 no problem (Chi^2 = [(data-model)/(error)]^2) and get a best-fit". What does that mean?

Comment: Can you fit a model by some method and show us a plot of the residuals? Probably you need to find a model and then a likelihood function, please give us more context!

Comment: My apologies; I was anticipating that there would be a standard way of doing this. The data I am fitting are photon fluxes from NASA. There are many factors that skew the errors in an asymmetric way. I know the errors are skewed as the data from the telescope returns fluxes with asymmetric upper and lower bounds. I am doing a  least-squares fit through Matlab. When we run the fit, we want to minimize the chi^2 value, where Chi is defined as the difference between what my model predicts subtracted by what we see in the sky, divided by the error at this energy value (independent variable).